# DAE simulation interrupts

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a problem using the MATLAB DAE-solvers.
I'm trying to simulate the behaviour of a mechanical system using lagrangien mechanics. To do so, I followed [the following tutorial](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/set-up-your-dae-problem.html) to use MATLAB'sDAE-solvers.

But when I ran my code, I got the following error message:

```
Warning: Failure at t=5.076437e-01.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed
(1.803513e-15) at time t.
 In ode15i (line 406)
```

Trying to find my mistake, I literally copied the code from the tutorial and ran it. The code is as follows:

```
syms l g m real 
syms x(t) y(t) T(t) 

eqns = [(m*diff(x(t),2) - T(t)/l*x(t)),
    (m*diff(y(t),2) - T(t)/l*y(t) + m*g),
    (x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 - l^2) ];

vars = [x(t); y(t); T(t)];

[eqns, vars] = reduceDifferentialOrder(eqns, vars);
if(~isLowIndexDAE(eqns, vars))
  [DAEs, DAEvars] = reduceDAEIndex(eqns, vars);
  [DAEs, DAEvars] = reduceRedundancies(DAEs, DAEvars);
end

%change to function, set parameters
f = daeFunction(DAEs, DAEvars, m, l, g);
m = 1.0;
r = 1.0;
g = 9.81;

F = @(t, Y, YP) f(t, Y, YP, m, r, g);

%get initial conditions
y0est = [0.5*r; -0.8*r; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
yp0est = zeros(7,1);
opt = odeset('RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));
[y0, yp0] = decic(F, 0, y0est, [], yp0est, [], opt);

%simulate
[t,y] = ode15i(F, [0, 5], y0, yp0, opt);
```

Comment: So, did that code work? What is your question?

Comment: There is a difference between [*Warnings* and *Errors*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/issue-warnings-and-errors.html)

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, it didn't work, that's why I'm asking. In the tutorial, they only run the simulation for 0.5 s, but when I run it for longer, it interrupts with the above Warning. So my question is: why does the simulation stop, and how can I avoid that?

Comment: "The page you were looking for does not exist. "

Comment: yeah, I noticed. They took the page down when updating to R2017a.